# Parsing OLEDB var types C#

Tags: c#, sql, parsing, variables, oledb

I am working on an app to read data from a OLESQL server.  Currently I'm just reading the data and inserting it into a string. I did some reading whenever I encounter a DBTYPE_WVARCHAR I can use myReader.GetString(index), however I am getting a crash when that happens. Here's the code I have so far.

```
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    int i =0;
    string FullRow = "";
    for(i=0;i<myReader.FieldCount;i++)
    {
         string type=myReader.GetDataTypeName(i);

         if ("DBTYPE_I4" == type)
         {
              FullRow += myReader.GetInt32(i);
         }
         else if ("Date" == type || "DBDate" == type || "DBTimeStamp" == type)
         {
              FullRow += myReader.GetDateTime(i).ToString();
         }
         else if("Char" == type || "LongVarChar" == type || "LongVarWChar" == type || "VarWChar" == type || "WChar" == type ){
              FullRow += myReader.GetString(i);
          }
         else if ("DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" == type)
          {
             FullRow += myReader.GetString(i); //Crash when this line gets hit
          }
          else
          {
                FullRow=FullRow;
          }
    }
    FullRow+=", ";
    Console.Write(FullRow);
}
```

Comment: "I am getting a crash" - presumably with an exception? What's the exception?

Comment: I could be wrong, but something is telling me that WVARCHAR is more of a multi-byte UniCode character not of a simple A-Z character.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am getting an InvalidCastException
And to DrApp Googlefu told my WVARCHAR is good to go via .GetString() I didn't see any .GetUnicodeString() :/also using
using System.Data.OleDb;

Comment: try `myReader.GetValue(i).ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

It's an odd problem because there are [examples](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/753281-how-access-one-value-excel-sheet-using-sql-statement-c) that use `GetString`, however an alternative would be:

```
FullRow += myReader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : myReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
```

Comment: Once again, thank you @D Stanley, it appears a field value of NULL really messes up the parsing system. I will just use isDBNull everything.

Comment: In your case you don't really need to check the source type since you're converting everything to strings anyways...